# Jenkins not picking up the nuget restored packages

Tags: jenkins, nuget, jenkins-plugins

I have defined below steps in `Jenkins`.

[image: Jenkins build configuration]

I can see that `NuGet` is restoring the packages on `Jenkins` console, but once `msbuild` starts building, it's failing with below error for all projects in the solution.

Error:

> "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.402\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error NETSDK1064: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers, version 2.1.3 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions."

If I restore the packages using `dotnet restore` command from command line and trigger the build then its getting passed. So something wrong in restoring the packages from first build step. What I am missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also used nuget.exe first with the same error (Only in Jenkins). Manually calling neget exe and msbuild was working fine. Now i use msbuild to restore dependencies and everything works well in jenkins

Comment: @Parashuram Please add the comment as answer and mark it as answer. It helps others alot. I found it helpful.

Comment: @MuhammadBashir. Done! Thanks for highlighting.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I got this working eventually. I am not sure if it's right or wrong and please correct me in case it's wrong. I am doing the restore using

```
MSBuild.exe /t:Restore MySln.sln
```

instead of `nuget restore` and this is successful now.

Comment: Had the exact same error with gitlab-ci, but it worked all the same

Comment: Same issue using Jenkins msbuild restore. Changing the -restore argument to /t:Restore worked

Comment: Had to do this after switching from package.config to PackageReference format.