# How to resolve NAnt not restoring package?

Tags: c#, nant

I am trying to build a project using NAnt, however, the project restore's error is: 
"\2.2.107\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(208,5): error NETSDK1064: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers, version 2.2.4 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions."

I tried this solution: [Jenkins not picking up the nuget restored packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417629/jenkins-not-picking-up-the-nuget-restored-packages)

This was unsuccessful.

```
<target name="restore" description="Restore the nuget packages">
    <exec program="${project::get-base-directory()}\.nuget\nuget.exe">
        <arg value="restore"/>
        <arg value="${project::get-base-directory()}\solution.sln"/>
    </exec>
  </target>

  <target name="build" description="Build Solution" depends="clean,restore">
    <call target="build-all"/>
  </target>

  <target name="build-all" description="Build the web and library solutions">
     <exec program="msbuild.exe">
        <arg value="solution.sln"/>
        <arg value="/m"/>
        <arg value="/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0"/>
        <arg value="/p:Configuration=Release"/>
        <arg value="/t:Clean"/>
        <arg value="/p:Configuration=Release"/>
      </exec>
      <exec program="msbuild.exe">
        <arg value="solution.sln"/>     
        <arg value="/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0"/>
        <arg value="/p:Configuration=Release"/>
        <arg value="/m"/>
        <arg value="/t:Build"/>
      </exec>
     </target>
```

Comment: what MSBuild version is being auto-detected by `nuget restore`?  Can you provide the output from that command?

Comment: @frankAlvaro      [exec] MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.9.21.664' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\bin'.

Comment: this a .NET Core project, right?  instead of `nuget.exe`, would `dotnet restore` do the trick, or would it yield the same error?

Comment: let me look up syntax for that and run it

Comment: Actually no it isnt a dotnet Core Project.

Answer (score 0):

Just for a reference: I had a .NET (not core) project which used package references. I added a argument in the msbuild exec to restore the nuget package and also specified nuget package path. I had pathing issue since the project got converted from 32-bit build to 64-bit build - it was inconsistently referencing between C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.nuget\packages and C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile.nuget\packages.

```
<exec program="${MSBuildPath}" workingdir="${build.dir}" failonerror="true" >
  <arg value="/v:d"/>
  <arg value="/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0"/>
  <arg value="/toolsversion:15.0"/>
  <arg value="/p:Configuration=release"/>
  <arg value="/p:Platform=Mixed Platforms"/>
  <arg value="/restore"/>
  <arg value="/restoreProperty:RestorePackagesPath=${NuGetPackagesPath}"/>
  <arg value="/fileLogger"/>
  <arg value="${project.name}.sln"/>
</exec>
```